# How do I create a List within a multi-dimensional array / grid c++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, grid-search

I have reached a stumbling block in my program. I am programming in c++ and using OpenGL for graphics. I am looking to partition the space with a grid (represented with a 2D array - grid[rows][cols]). The grid will have 'cells' at each index.

Within this grid and at each INDEX location i.e. grid[0][0] I want a list of object ID's (int values) to be collected as they move into each grid cell. The list at index location grid[0][0] should be updating in real-time / dynamically with moving objects on the screen.

I want to retrieve the object ID's as they populate the list for collision checking later.

As a visual it should be as follows:

Grid Array

+[0][0]         --> List[]

+[0][1]         --> List[]

+[0][2]         --> List[]

+[0][3]     --> List[]

+[1][0]         --> List[]

+[1][1]         --> List[]
...and so on

Is there a way to do this in C++? Java seems to be able to create new arrays within array spots as I need...there must be a way?

Hash tables, linked lists are so far over my head...but if they are what I need to know then please let me know and I will look into them in more detail...
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::list<ID>>>` or something?

Comment: maybe thats one of the rare cases, where a `std::vector<int>[][]` is appropriate

Comment: are the dimensions of the grid fixed or dynamic?

Comment: Have you considered spatial hashing? That's a common approach for "divide space into grid and check collisions in each cell"... But if you want to start with a 2D array that's fine.

Comment: @  user463035818 - grid is fixed size, equal i.e. 10 x 10

Comment: @ Max Langhof thanks for your comment. Do you have good resource for spatial hashing, preferably for a beginner? Those sort of topics are difficult to understand I find .. many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

// some data
struct DATA
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    vector<vector<list<DATA>>> matrix_of_lists;
    matrix_of_lists.resize(2);
    matrix_of_lists[0].resize(2);
    matrix_of_lists[1].resize(2);

    DATA d;
    d.x = 1;
    matrix_of_lists[0][0].push_back(d);

    cout << matrix_of_lists[0][0].front().x;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are storing `shared_ptr`s of `list`s instead of just the lists themselves?

Comment: @snake_style, I've implemented and tried the code you suggested and it seems to be unable to accept more data pushed back to the same location i.e. matrix_of_lists[0][0].push_back(d2), matrix_of_lists[0][0].push_back(d3) etc... Can this method accomplish this?

Comment: @snake_style, I figured it out - it did technically work first time but I couldn't print out all the list. Now I use for (auto const& c : matrix_of_lists[0][0])
 {
  cout << c << ' '; //prints out 
 }; .........Thanks a lot!